# Javascript / jQuery Prototype inheritance extend defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

is there any way how to extend default options for multiple Prototype based Javascript constructor functions?

I'm trying to get the options object in Events object, is it possible?

```
var Website = function(options){
    this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
}

Website.prototype = {

    constructor : Website,

    defaults: {
        navigation: $('#navigation'),
        footer : $('#footer')
    }


    init: function(){

    }

};



var Events = function(){
    this.init()
}

Events.prototype = {

    constructor: Website,

    init:function(){
      console.log(...)
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any inheritance between `Events` and `Website` here? Do you just want `Event.prototype.defaults = Website.prototype.defaults`?

Comment: I would like to know, how i can get the properties or the defaults object from the Website and use them inside Events object, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, just access `Website.prototype.defaults`!

Comment: Thank you, and is there some way how to access the property options that is in Website and use it inside object Events?

Comment: There are no objects (instances) anywhere in your code? If you had one, you could of course easily access its `.options` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a significant rewrite, but i'd suggest storing the defaults in an outside variable that both "classes" can share:

```
var App = (function ($) {

    var defaults = {
        navigation: "nav",
        footer : "foot"
    };



    var Website = function (options) {

      this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.echo =  function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        };

    };

    var Events = function (options) {

      this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.echoTwo = function (message) {
            console.log(message + message);
        };
    };

    return {
        Website: Website,
        Events: Events
    };
}(jQuery));

var website = new App.Website({navigation: "changed"});
website.echo(website.options.navigation + ' '+ website.options.footer); // "changed foot"

var events = new App.Events({footer: "bar"}); //
events.echoTwo(events.options.navigation + ' '+ events.options.footer); // "nav barnav bar"
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iyecev/1/edit)

This way, you can set the shared `options` through a variable only available in the scope of the wrapping, self-invoking function. The structure and nomenclature is a little fuzzy, but hopefully the general idea is clear.

**Edit**

I've restructured things to allow each "class" to have it's own options set on instantiation. You could do the same to set the defaults for `App` as well.

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to figure it out is: How to Have multiple objects written with constructor functions and access properties and call the methods inside another object. Im trying to make separate objects for better organization of code.

Here is my example : [link] (http://jsbin.com/ocezep/1/edit)